# Cauchy estimates and the maximum principle

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle, entire-functions

I am stuck at a step in a problem where I've been given hints. The hints confuse me, so I'm hoping for some help.

Assuming that $f$ is entire and that $$|f(z)| \leq |z| + 1/|z|, $$ for $z \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\},$ I wish to show that $f(z)$ is of the form $az+b$.

I want to use the taylor expansion of $f$, so that $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n. $$

The hints say to use the Cauchy estimates and the maximum principle to show that $$|a_n|r^n \leq \max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|\leq r + 1/r, $$

so that as $r \rightarrow \infty$, we get $a_n = 0$ for $n \geq 2$.

It is the first inequality that confuses me. The maximum principle says that if $|f(z)| \leq M$ for $|z| = r$, then $|f(z)| \leq M$ for $|z| \leq r$. But I don't see how that is even relevant in this case. And I've had even less luck using the Cauchy estimates.

Comment: There is no such thing as a function which “is entire in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$”. An entire function is an analytic function from $\mathbb C$ into itself.

Comment: Very good point, and sorry, that was my bad, and very reckless of me! The function is assumed to be entire, and the condition that $|f(z)| \leq |z|+1/|z|$ holds in $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: Which part is unclear, $|a_n|r^n \leq \max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$ or $ \max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|\leq r + 1/r$? Or why that implies $a_n=0$ for $n \ge 2$?

Comment: The part that is unclear to me is $|a_n|r^n \leq \max_{|z|=r} |f(z)|$. @MartinR

Comment: @j.eee: That follows from Cauchy's integral formula for the derivatives, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Consequences.